# How to fill missing date witht the max of date in the date column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill a missing value in a date column with the max of the date in the same column. however with the below code provided, it is not getting transformed.

```
us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].fillna(us_copy.groupby('Vendor_Name')['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].max())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original:

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'])

s = us_copy.groupby('Vendor_Name')['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].transform('max')
us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].fillna(s)
```

EDIT: If need repalce by max of all column values:

```
#if necessary convert to datetimes
us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'])

a = us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].max()
us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].fillna(a)
```

Comment: i am still getting NaT

Comment: @YogeshGovindan - Are there datetimes? What is `print (us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].dtype)` ?

Comment: dtype('<M8[ns]')

Comment: @YogeshGovindan - And if use `us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'])` still failed solution?

Comment: still no luck.. the same NaT

Comment: @YogeshGovindan - Can you share first 3 rows? Or is possible in group are only `NaT` ?

Comment: us_copy['Inv_Latest_Document_Date'].max() is Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00') and i need to impute the same in the missing which is showing as NAT

Comment: @YogeshGovindan - But per groups? Or by max of all values?